# Metaplex findByMint() shows 'pending' instead of actual NFTs

Tags: metaplex, nft, metaplex-js

I am following the the [Metaplex Examples Repository](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-examples/blob/main/getting-started-expressjs/index.cjs) [recommended by the metaplex docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/getting-started):

```
const getNFT = async () => {
  const nft = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .findByMint(testIdentityTokenIssuer.publicKey);

  console.log(json.stringify(nft));
}
```

Returns:

```
{
  status: "pending",
  children: [],
  context: {},
  eventEmitter: {
    _events: {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
  },
}
```

This kind of looks like an unresolved promise, but I'm `await`ing the result so it would have resolved at this point. **How can I see the NFTs when using `findByMint()`**?

Answer (score 1):

Answering own question to help others:

My code is missing `.run()` - this is needed to execute the transaction:

```
const nft = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .findByMint(testIdentityTokenIssuer.publicKey)
    .run();
```

The example in the docs is also missing the `run()` - I've raised an issue about this.